# How to map 3 references using the same column in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have following Ticket class:

```
public class Ticket {
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Type Type { get; set; }
  public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
  public virtual State State { get; set; }
}
```

that maps to a table in legacy database with the following mapping:

```
public TicketMap()
{
    Table("TICKET");
    LazyLoad();
    Id(x => x.Id)
        .GeneratedBy.TriggerIdentity()
        .Column("ID")
        .Access.Property()
        .Not.Nullable();
    References(x => x.Type)
        .Class<Type>()
        .Cascade.None()
        .LazyLoad()
        .Columns("TYPE_ID");
    References(x => x.Status)
        .Class<Status>()
        .Cascade.None()
        .Columns("STATUS_ID", "TYPE_ID");
    References(x => x.State)
        .Class<State>()
        .Cascade.None()
        .LazyLoad()
        .Columns("STATE_ID", "TYPE_ID");
}
```

The problem is that when I try to save a Ticket with State and Status NHibernate doesn't know which TYPE_ID to use and fails to save the entity.

Both State and Status classes have composite keys (which I know is a bad practice but, as mentioned above, it's legacy database and I'm not able to create surrogate keys).

I there a way to make this reference work?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to make these properties read-only. In xml configuration (xml mapping is world I know) it would look like this (the same for other two ref types: Type, State):

```
<many-to-one name="Status" insert="false" update="false" >
  <column name="STATUS_ID" />
  <column name="TYPE_ID" />
</many-to-one>
...
```

And then create protected artificial properties

```
<property name="StatusId" column="STATUS_ID" insert="true" update="true" />
<property name="StateId" column="STATE_ID" /><!-- above insert and update attr are redundant -->
<property name="TypeId" column="TYPE_ID" />
```

These properties should be declared as protected on the Ticket entity. With some internal logic, they can be set to proper values based on selected State, Status or Type.

What we get, is full access to query engine, because all 3 reference types can be used for filtering. And Insert/update will work as well, 'cause NHibernate exactly knows which value to use.